# finding the smallest good number

Tags: c, algorithm

My C programming problem is to find the smallest good n-digit numeral. the sequence is 1213, then the user inputs a number, the number of times the 1213 appears will depend on the input.  for example:

```
(input: 1   output:1)      (input:2    output:12)  (input:3    output:121)   (input:4  output: 1213)  (input:5 output:12131)  (input:6   output:121312)    (input:7    output: 1213121)
```

the sequence will be repeated, the number inputted will tell how many digits of the sequence will appear on the output, but the sequence should be followed, 1213

Noww what i have created so far is:

```
include<stdio.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>  
main() 
{   
    int a, x, num, ar[500]  
    printf("Input an integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&a);  
    printf("The smallest good number of %d number": );  
    scanf("%d", &num);  ar[x]=num; 
}
```

That is only to ask the user to input a number and then I don't know how to make the 1213 thing.

Comment: Why do you read 2 numbers? Isn't 1 enough? Do you want something like that: https://ideone.com/d4EeYX ?

Comment: I assume the 1213 is not fixed.

Comment: Put your "good number" sequence in an array, one digit per element.  Then when they enter their number, do a for loop with that many iterations and output the element equal to the loop number modulo the length of the original array.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{ unsigned int a, num, i, len; char result[500], aStr[9];
  printf("\nInput a positive integer less than 8 digits: "); scanf("%u", &a);  
  printf("\nInput a number of digits between 1 and 500: "); scanf("%u", &num);

  // convert the input number a to string aStr and calculate its length
  snprintf(aStr, 9, "%u", a); len = strlen(aStr);
  // print the digits in result until the desired length is reached
  for(i=0; i < num; i++) result[i] = aStr[i % len];
  *i = 0; // terminate the string
  printf("The smallest good number is: %s\n", aStr);

  return 0;
}
```